# In java, need some data collector which will sort strings(like tree)

Tags: java

I want to store names in a data structure for the time the program runs. When I receive a new name, I want to be able to check if it is already inside the structure as fast as possible.

I thought of using a sorted heap, but I don't know how to deal with it in java.

Comment: `select count(*) from table where name = ?`  ????

Comment: To hold those names in a data structure(for the time the program runs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to check existence, a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) would be the most efficient structure from a performance perspective:

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size)

If you also need to iterate over the names in a specific order (say alphabetical) then you can use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead:

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).

Comment: Note: If you need advanced search capabilities, you should use a specialised library instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for some tree based datastructures in `Java`, check `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` to begin with. These will give you typical O(logn) kind of average search time and keep data in sorted order.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) it's better for your task than any standard java Set implementation.